# Using API authentication with shared python code

Tags: python, api, github, oauth, github-api

I am working on a python script that uses github's api. I intend to share the code with someone to show them how the script works.

Because I cross github's query limit as an anonymous user, I need to have an authentication. What form of authentication should I use in my script since I am sharing it?

Comment: Make the token configurable, then let them use their own token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Hang stated, I used github's personal access token. This is what I did.

```
token='my_token'
url='https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=python'
rslt=requests.get(url,headers={'Authorization':auth})
```